# FALA-SE "êlis góstam" ou "êlis góstão"?

Tags: verbos, fonologia

Estou lendo um livro de gramática de 1871, e nele a 3ª pessoa do plural do presente do indicativo ("gostam, amam, sentem, etc) é escrito como "gostão, amão" e, acho eu que, se fala como "góstão e âmão".

Eu, então, comecei a pensar "caramba, se parece muito com o que eu falo e ouço". Eu tentei falar "falam" como [ˈfa.lɐ̃ŋ] (/ŋ/ é do meu dialeto) e me pareceu esquisito, no sentido de não me ser natural. Isso meu deixou pensando: eu, aparentemente, falo "falam" como "fálão"/[ˈfa.lɐ̃ʊ̯̃ŋ] (transcrição de como **EU** falo); e, também, há várias pessoas, no Brasil, que se confundem se é "morram" ou "morrão". Mesmo sendo ou um erro de falta de estudo ou preguiça ou descaso, merece atenção.

Então, será que — pelo menos, onde vivo — se fala "falam" como "fálão"? Se sim, será que é porque não mudou no processo?

Isso também acontece com "falaram, cantaram, quiseram", que falam-se como "falárão, cantárão e quisérão".

P.S.: nas transcrições fonéticas, eu usei o AFI/IPA; e as transcrições foram feitas da maneira que eu falo por poder ser apenas algo do meu dialeto.

O livro: https://archive.org/details/grammaticaportu00reisgoog.

P.S.2.: na realidade, no meu dialeto, as duas pronúncias coexistem, mas a da qual falei é extremamente mais forte. O "o" em "fálão" também pode ficar mais fraco, o que é mais difícil de se ouvir, mas ele 'tá lá!

P.S.3.: "falam" como "fálão" tem duas pronúncias: [ˈfa.lɐ̃ʊ̯̃ŋ] e [ˈfa.lɐ̃ʊ̯̃]. Por isso "me" e "mim" têm sons diferentes: "mi" e "miŋ" / [mɪ] e [ˈmĩŋ].

Comment: +1 No meu dialeto (noroeste do Paraná) e em todos os que me lembro de ter ouvido (em pt-BR) também. Agora, pronunciando com /m/ no final ao invés do /ŋ/, penso que é muito difícil perceber a diferença entre /fálam/ e /fálão/, e essencialmente impossível (de novo, no meu dialeto), se a boca não chegar a se fechar para o /m/.

Answer (score 8):

(Pessoal, há tempo que acompanho o Portuguese Stack Exchange — e absolutamente o adoro —, mas esta é a minha primeira resposta aqui, então ainda estou me habituando. Queria comentar algumas coisas à parte na pergunta original, mas ainda não tenho pontuação suficiente para isso. :( Se, de algum modo, esta minha resposta fugir ao propósito, avisem-me para que eu possa aprender e editar. Obrigado!)

Bem, este tópico de vogais e ditongos nasais é um dos meus prediletos sobre a fonologia da língua, então vou tentar dar a minha contribuição aqui. Para as transcrições fonéticas aqui na resposta, vou ignorar o **[ŋ]** alofônico que você usou no seu texto original e usar as transcrições fonêmicas gerais para simplificar. Há muita variação na real pronúncia das vogais nasais na língua portuguesa e não é o foco da pergunta, mas imagino que, se de fato há um **[ŋ]** alofônico nas suas vogais nasais, você deva ser de algum estado do Sul/Sudeste. Sou baiano e posso te garantir que as nossas vogais aqui são absolutamente nasais por si só, normalmente sem nenhum apoio de consoantes nasais — para falar a verdade, os dialetos nordestinos são conhecidos por ser é "exageradamente" nasalizados na sua alofonia, hahaha. Também acho improvável que o seu **/ɐ̃/** seja realmente **[ɐ̃]** — que acredito que seja de fato [a pronúncia usada pelos portugueses](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-gestual/ma%C3%A7%C3%A3) e a diferença é bem clara para mim; nós, brasileiros, normalmente variamos entre algo como **[[ə̃]~[ɜ̃]~[ɜ]](https://forvo.com/word/ma%C3%A7%C3%A3/#pt_br)** (sim, esta última possibilidade desnasalizada, algo bem característico dos sotaques paulistas e sulistas, por exemplo).

A resposta curta e direta à sua pergunta é que, sim, "falam" e "gostam" se pronunciam como "fálão" (**/ˈfa.lɐ̃w̃/**) e "góstão" (**/ˈgɔs.tɐ̃w̃/**) — e não como um erro ou possibilidade dialetal; [essas são as pronúncias corretas dessas palavras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology#Nasal_diphthongs) —; durante toda a minha vida, nunca vi um nativo pronunciá-las de outra forma (por exemplo, como **/ˈfa.lɐ̃/** e **/ˈgɔs.tɐ̃/**, como proposto). Na ortografia da língua, o dígrafo "am" só representa a vogal nasal **/ɐ̃/** isolada quando não se encontra no fim de palavra; nessa posição, sempre representa o ditongo nasal **/ɐ̃w̃/** (e é sempre conjugação de terceira pessoa do plural de verbo!), tendo, portanto, o mesmo valor fonêmico que o dígrafo "ão". (Também em nenhum dos casos a consoante M é de fato pronunciada como **/m/**, exceto em alguns dialetos como um apoio alofônico, já que é sempre seguida de uma outra consoante bilabial e a nasalidade da vogal pode gerar um "resquício de M" (por exemplo, "tambor": **/tɐ̃.ˈboʁ/** -> **[tɜ̃.ˈboɾ]** -> **[tɜ̃ᵐ.ˈboɾ]**).) O dígrafo "an", por sua vez, é que sempre representa a vogal nasal **/ɐ̃/** pura, independentemente da posição em que esteja na palavra; porém, acredito que seja muito raro no fim de palavras — tive de pesquisar aqui, pois não me lembrava de cabeça, e só achei palavras importadas, como "slogan" e o nome "Jean" (que também foi [importado do francês](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jean#Portuguese)). Portanto, fora essas poucas palavras terminadas em "an", a única forma de representar a vogal nasal **/ɐ̃/** no fim de uma palavra é com "ã", como em "pagã".

E aí isso nos leva à sua outra pergunta: Por que houve, então, a mudança ortográfica? Bem, eu pessoalmente não tenho essa resposta (acabei de ver que o Jacinto já cobriu essa parte), mas o que sei é que, atualmente, na língua, além da função de nasalizar as vogais A e O, o til também possui uma função secundária de indicar a tonicidade da palavra, exceto se houver um acento, caso no qual tal acento detém a primazia tônica e o til passa a indicar apenas a nasalidade da vogal ou ditongo em questão ("ímã", "órfã(o)", "Estêvão", "bênção", etc.). Logo, hoje em dia escrevem-se as conjugações de terceira pessoa do plural com "am" porque, se se escrevessem com "ão", precisaríamos dum acento extra para indicar a tonicidade da sílaba predecessora, como estamos usando aqui para indicar a pronúncia: "fálão", "góstão". Não conheço a gramática em torno de 1871, mas imagino, então, que à época o til fosse um indicador apenas de nasalidade e a tonicidade fosse determinada por algum outro conjunto de regras ortográficas (que não pude inferir apenas pela ortografia das palavras que você usou de exemplo).

O dígrafo "am" não é o único dígrafo nasal da língua que deixa de ser dígrafo e passa a representar de fato um ditongo quando vem na última sílaba duma palavra. O mesmo ocorre com o dígrafo "em", que, normalmente, representa a vogal nasal **/ẽ/**, mas que passa a representar o ditongo nasal **/ẽj̃/** no fim de palavras (**/ɐ̃j̃/** em parte do português europeu, mesclando-se, portanto, com o ditongo representado por "ãe"): "bem" não é pronunciado em nenhum dialeto como **/bẽ/**, mas sim como **/bẽj̃/** no Brasil e **/bɐ̃j̃/** em parte de Portugal. Aliás, a vogal nasal **/ẽ/** comporta-se ainda de modo mais peculiar que a vogal nasal **/ɐ̃/**; enquanto **/ɐ̃/** é possível no fim de palavras tanto com o til em "ã" quanto com o dígrafo "an" (vá lá: salvo engano, apenas em palavras importadas, mas que, uma vez dicionarizadas, já fazem parte do nosso idioma oficialmente), **/ẽ/** é oficialmente impossível de aparecer no fim de palavras. Não que não o consigamos produzir fisicamente, mas não há palavras oficiais em que isso ocorra; a combinação "en" no fim de palavras produz igualmente o ditongo nasal **/ẽj̃/** no Brasil e, excepcionalmente, **/ɛn/** em Portugal (o que acho interessantíssimo, já que a nossa língua normalmente não possui consoantes nasais pronunciadas no fim de sílabas, sendo elas apenas uma forma de nasalizar a vogal precedente): "abdômen", **/ab.'do.mẽj̃/** (**[äb̚.'do.mẽj̃]~[äbi.'dõ.mẽj̃]**, etc.), no Brasil e "abdómen", **/ɐb.ˈdɔ.mɛn/** (**[[ɐβ.ˈðɔ.mɛn]](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-gestual/abd%C3%B4men)**), em Portugal. Bem, fica aqui a observação de que essa grande revolução fonológica que seria a possibilidade de haver **/ẽ/** no fim de palavras reside nas mãos dos nossos grandes lexicógrafos, pois marginalmente isso já acontece: basta que um dicionário oficialize as gírias, ubiquamente utilizadas no Brasil, "man" ou "men" (pronunciadas como **/mẽ/**) ou mesmo o vocativo "nem" (**/nẽ/**), absolutamente comum aqui na Bahia e altamente irritante ("ô, neeeeem, vem cá"), e teremos oficialmente estendido as possibilidades fonológicas da nossa língua. ;)

(Enquanto escrevia esta resposta, descobri que, em Portugal, utilizam "íman" em vez de "ímã" e, à semelhança do fenômeno que descrevi de palavras como "abdômen/abdómen", "sêmen/sémen"..., essa palavra é pronunciada não com **/ɐ̃/** no fim (**/ˈi.mɐ̃/**), mas com a sequência **/ɐn/** (**[/ˈi.mɐn/](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-gestual/%C3%ADman)**), o que configura uma outra exceção à não pronunciação natural do **/n/** no fim de sílabas na nossa língua. Que da hora! Aparentemente o mesmo é feito com a palavra "slogan", por exemplo (ou quase o mesmo, já que, segundo a Infopédia, seria com **/a/** aberto mesmo: **[/ˈsloɡan/](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/slogan)**). Pergunto-me se também é assim que se pronuncia "Jean" por lá. Algum português pode esclarecer-me?)

Ainda nessa questão de dígrafos nasais que deixam de ser dígrafos no fim de palavras, o dígrafo "om", que normalmente representa a vogal nasal **/õ/**, também pode representar — porém aqui marginalmente e com muita variação entre os dialetos — o ditongo **/õw̃/** ("bom": **[bõ]~[bõw̃]**). Acredito que teoricamente também seja possível acontecer o mesmo com os dígrafos "im" e "um", mas a inserção da semivogal necessária à formação do ditongo meio que seria redundante em relação à sua vogal correspondente, imagino (por exemplo: "assim" como **[a.ˈsĩ]~[a.ˈsĩj̃]** e "atum" como **[a.ˈtũ]~[a.ˈtũw̃]**). Até porque normalmente a tendência, pelo menos no Brasil, é deletar a semivogal em contextos assim e não inserir uma ("contínuo": **/kõ.ˈti.nu.u/** -> **[kõ.ˈt͡ʃi.nwu]~[kõ.ˈt͡ʃi.nu]**).

Portanto, a diferença que o ANeves diz que não consegue perceber entre "ão" e "am" e sobre a qual o Schilive está aqui perguntando seria, teoricamente, a diferença entre o ditongo **/ɐ̃w̃/** (como em "pão") e a vogal pura **/ɐ̃/** (como em "tampa"); porém, no fim de palavras, essa diferença deixa de existir e "am" passa a assumir a pronúncia do ditongo **/ɐ̃w̃/** também, sendo utilizado no lugar de "ão" apenas por uma questão de tonicidade. É por isso que muitos cometem o erro de escrever "falam" como "falão", por exemplo, pois todo nativo consegue perceber intuitivamente o ditongo na pronúncia dessa palavra, errando apenas por não conhecer as regras ortográficas em questão e não perceber que "falão" seria pronunciada como oxítona (normalmente nativos cometem erros de ortografia por desconhecer alguma regra específica de escrita, mas escrevendo pelo julgamento auditivo — ironicamente preciso, muitas vezes — que fazem da palavra). Do mesmo modo, portanto, as conjugações de terceira pessoa do plural do pretérito perfeito e do futuro do presente possuem exatamente os mesmos sons, diferenciando-se apenas em relação à sílaba tônica — por exemplo: "gostaram" (**/gos.'ta.ɾɐ̃w̃/**) e "gostarão" (**/gos.ta.'ɾɐ̃w̃/**. Aqui de modo geral e particularmente no Brasil, pois imagino que em Portugal sejam, estritamente, diferentes, por causa do primeiro A, que se torna átono, em "gostarão": **/guʃ.'ta.ɾɐ̃w̃/** e **/guʃ.tɐ.'ɾɐ̃w̃/**, respectivamente).

Por tudo que expus, sim, é extremamente não natural pronunciar "falam" como **/ˈfa.lɐ̃/**, que seria a pronúncia de uma hipotética palavra "fálã". Você mencionou que, no seu dialeto, as duas pronúncias coexistem e eu fiquei curioso, Schilive, pois acho extremamente improvável que **/ˈfa.lɐ̃/** de fato seja possível. De onde você é? Haha. Pergunto porque isso me lembra uma coisa curiosa que percebi há um tempo por alguns vídeos: nos chamados "sotaques colonos" do Rio Grande do Sul, notei que algumas pessoas pronunciavam "não" como algo como "nõ" (aparentemente reduzindo o ditongo "ão" a apenas "õ"). Essa percepção foi-me confirmada por um conhecido da região, que me afirmou que isso de fato ocorre, mas não cheguei a tentar fazer uma análise fonética mais aprofundada. Imagino que seja possível que o que ocorra seja o seguinte: **/nɐ̃w̃/** -> **[nɜ̃ʊ̃]~[nə̃ʊ̃]** -> **[nʊ̃]**. Pelo mesmo processo, "falam" poderia tornar-se **[ˈfa.lʊ̃]** e isso poderia ser interpretado de diferentes formas — para mim poderia soar como "fálõ", mas, para você, "fálã". É uma hipótese só! =)

Espero ter contribuído com a minha primeira resposta aqui no site e desculpem-me se me estendi demais!

Comment: Natan, bem-vindo ao site. Achei a tua resposta muito interessante. Respondendo a algumas das tuas interrogações, antes da ortografia "moderna", 1911 em Portugal, 1943 no Brasil, não se indicava a sílaba tónica. Os acentos eram usados para distinguir palavras escritas com as mesmas letras mas não homófonas (*sêde* versus *séde*, *pégada* ’marca do pé’ versus *pegada* de *pegar*; mas nem todos se preocupavam com isto) e só acessoriamente indicavam a sílaba tónica (*amará* versus *amára*; punham acento nas duas), um pouco o oposto do que fazemos agora -- o acento indica >>

Comment: >> a vogal tónica e acessoriamente o timbre. O /ẽ/ pode ocorrer no fim de palavra no sul de Portugal. Aqui *bem* tem as três pronúncias: para a maioria é /bẽj̃/, como no Brasil, ou /bɐ̃j̃/ (rima com *mãe*); e pode ainda ser /bẽ/. Creio que a Infopédia se enganou no *slogan*: a pronúncia é /'slo.gɐn/; o /a/ átono seria muito pouco natural naquela posição. O [m] também pode ocorrer em fim de palavra em Portugal: /'mɔ.dɛm/; há uma tendência a manter uma pronúncia de palavras estrangeiras próxima da original. Pá, eu não conheço nenhum Jean; não sei se existe uma pronúncia lusitana desse nome; >>

Comment: >> Se me apresentassem um Jean brasileiro eu tenderia a imitar a pronúncia brasileira, que imagino que seja como *Jeã*. O único *Jean* brasileiro que me lembro de ouvir foi na rádio e televisão inglesas (o triste caso do Jean Charles em Londres) e não presumi que a pronúncia deles fosse a brasileira.

Comment: @Natan, não sei se é para eu responder, mas…  Eu sou de SP, São Bernardo do Campo. E eu ouço "falam" como "fálam" quando alguém corta ("eu fi' arr cois' lá, ma' n' deu cert'") ou de vez em quando (perto de vez em nunca), é bem raro. Obrigado pela ÓTIMA resposta

Comment: Conheces algum lugar no qual eu poderia pesquisar mais sobre? Obrigado, de novo, pela incrível resposta.

Comment: Fiz uma alteração na pergunta, por sinal.

Comment: Ótima resposta! Mas tentaria sintetizar um pouco mais o conteúdo e escrever um pouco menos no futuro, hahaha

Comment: Também sugeria que explorasses mais as opções de edição de texto (blockquote, centralizar, usar tópicos,...) para evitar que a resposta seja só 'texto corrido' e seja mais fácil de ler!

Answer (score 6):

A nossa ortografia não pretende estabelecer uma correspondência biunívoca entre símbolo e som. A letra m em fim de palavra apenas indica nasalidade: não existe nenhum som [m] em *falam*, tal como também não existe em *fim* ou *bem*.

As terminações *-am* e *-ão* são meras representações convencionais do mesmo fonema: *acordam* (de *acordar*) e *acórdão* (substantivo) são homófonos; *pensam* rima com *bênção*, *órgão* com *outorgam*, *orégão* com *entregam*, *órfão* com *morfam*.

Porque é que temos estas duas maneiras de representar o mesmo som? Basicamente é herança histórica. Só no século XX é que a língua portuguesa teve ortografia regulada por lei. Antes, especialmente em tempos recuados, reinava uma grande variedade de grafias, encontrando-se a mesma palavra escrita de diversas maneiras na mesma obra.

Por exemplo, na primeira edição d’[*Os Lusíadas*, 1572](http://purl.pt/1), encontramos *eram* e *erão* (quando muito, hoje escreveríamos *érão*; naqueles tempos não se pensava necessário assinalar a sílaba tónica), *vieram* e *vierão, deixam* e *deixão, contam* e *contão*, *não* e *nam*, *razão* e *razam, capitão* e *capitam*, etc.

No entanto, no final do século XIX, a grafia mais comum já coincidia com a nossa neste ponto. Formas como *falão* ou *capitam* já eram raras nessa altura. De modo que as leis ortográficas do século XX simplesmente consagraram, neste ponto, aquilo que já então era a prática mais comum.

Porque é que os escritores acabaram por preferir *falam* a *fálão*, *falaram* a *falárão*, mas *falarão* a *falarám*? Possivelmente pela mesma razão que Cândido de Figueiredo preferiu adotar essas grafias no seu *Novo Dicionário da Língua Portuguesa* de 1899, que foi basicamente indicar a sílaba tónica sem usar acentos (p. XVIII – XIX; grafia original; só consegui linkar a [edição de 1913](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Candido_de_Figueiredo_1913/Orth.)):

> Já agora, não farei ponto nêste capítulo, sem uma ligeira referência ás terminações verbaes *ão* e *am*, e ao suffixo *izar*.

> Aquellas terminações têm variado de fórma no decurso dos tempos; e a philogogia acha-as ambas legítimas, sejam ellas oxýtonas ou paroxýtonas. E, assim, eruditos philólogos escrevem o pretérito *louvárão* e o futuro *louvarão*, em quanto outros orthographam *louváram* e *louvarám*.

> Ao mesmo tempo, o uso mais generalizado apresenta-nos o pretérito *louváram* e o futuro *louvarão;* e, visto que as duas terminações são igualmente legítimas, visto que a adopção exclusiva de uma importa dispêndio de accentos num país que tão avesso lhes é, e visto parecêr-me útil que a terminação *ão* pertença em regra ás palavras oxýtonas e a fórmas mònòsyllábicas, (*dão, são, tão*) acceito e pratico o alludido uso, hôje generalizado, de se escrever o pretérito *louvaram*, o futuro *louvarão*, o presente *dão* e *são*.

> A philologia não soffre com êste uso, e lucra-se alguma coisa, creio, em simplicidade e em coherência.

Este princípio da simplicidade não se estendeu aos substantivos: temos *acórdão, bênção, orégão, órfão, órgão*, enquanto o princípio adotado para os verbos ditaria *bençam, orfam*, etc.

Comment: Obrigado pela ótima resposta, @Jacinto.